# Python os.system('python') only works in the shell

Tags: python, shell, cmd

I want to access the cmd version of the python shell, by using`os.system('python')`
However, this only works from the python shell, and not from the program. This is especially confusing considering if I wanted to use `os.system('cmd')`it would run from the program. What am I doing so that the python shell cannot be opened through a command in a program? And why does it work for cmd?

Comment: To clarify, are you attempting to open an interactive python shell from within a python script?

Comment: I have no idea; `os.system("python")` works fine for me in both interactive and script (program) mode.  Can you post your code and the actual output you get?  I followed mine with an input command, to make sure nothing would close down while I was looking for solutions.

Comment: Works for me. However, I am using Linux. Maybe Windows has problems associating a terminal window with Python?

Comment: And presumably you are on Windows? I just tried it on Fedora 24 and there is no problem.

Comment: Yes, I am on windows.

Comment: 'import os' 'os.system('python')' I get no output

Comment: There is no "cmd version" of the Python shell. You're trying to run python.exe, which attaches to or allocates a console (not a cmd shell).  Using `system` depends on your `PATH` environment variable. If you want this to just work, use `subprocess.call('python.exe')`. This should always run the version of Python you're currently using because `CreateProcess` checks the application directory first before system directories and `PATH`.

Comment: Maybe Python isn't in your path. Specify the full path to `python.exe` in your `os.system` call.

Comment: @MarkRansom, `os.system` should be avoided if possible, and in this case definitely because `subprocess.call('python.exe')` is guaranteed to work for a standard Python installation that's already running via python.exe or pythonw.exe.

Comment: @eryksun I'm not up on the nuances of making system calls, it's not something I do often, so thanks. Why didn't you leave that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you have a python script, and you want to be able to open an interactive python shell at some point during the execution of the script.  If that is what you want, then this should work:

```
import code

# do some stuff
# open interactive python shell using the code library
code.interact(local=locals())
```